# Proj.NET and Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql, database, geospatial

I have found this project on Codeplex.

http://www.codeplex.com/ProjNET

I need to integrate this code with Sql Server 2008, and found a similar project on the Web

http://sqlspatialtools.codeplex.com/

The second one can be bound to Sql Server. What do i need to do, to "bind" the first one, the same way as the first?

**EDIT** using code like create assembly and functions in Sql Server, Sql Spatial tools is bound to SQL.

I'm not sure i made myself clear, but if i take the same approach, all i need is to register the first one, the same way as the second?

http://sqlspatialtools.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/changeset/view/23749?projectName=sqlspatialtools#255008 (check SQL Scripts->register.sql)

Any light on this matter?

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Studying the .sql file on Sql Spatial tools em and another friend was able to find the correct pathway that we needed.

We builded a function on ProjNet API, and then in Sql Server 2008 we did this:

create assembly ProjNET 'pathToFile'
go

create function ourFunction(signature) returns geography
as external projnet.ourNamespace.Function

Thanks for the attention everyone.

G.